# Display local JSON data on Angular 9 template

Tags: arrays, angular, ionic-framework

I'd like to display the following JSON in my HTML template

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Get All Data",
    "Description": "Returns all data in the system. Warning: this request returns 8MB+ and takes 5+ seconds",
    "Path": "/all",
    "Params": null
  },
  {
    "Name": "Get List Of Countries",
    "Description": "Returns all countries and associated provinces. The country_slug variable is used for country specific data",
    "Path": "/countries",
    "Params": null
  },
  {
    "Name": "Get List Of Cases Per Country Per Province By Case Type",
    "Description": "Returns all cases by case type for a country. Country must be the country_slug from /countries. Cases must be one of: confirmed, recovered, deaths",
    "Path": "/country/{country}/status/{status}",
    "Params": [
      "country",
      "status"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Get List Of Cases Per Country Per Province By Case Type With Live Count",
    "Description": "Returns all cases by case type for a country with the latest record being the live count. Country must be the country_slug from /countries. Cases must be one of: confirmed, recovered, deaths",
    "Path": "/country/{country}/status/{status}/live",
    "Params": [
      "country",
      "status"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Get List Of Cases Per Country By Case Type",
    "Description": "Returns all cases by case type for a country. Country must be the country_slug from /countries. Cases must be one of: confirmed, recovered, deaths",
    "Path": "/total/country/{country}/status/{status}",
    "Params": [
      "country",
      "status"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Get List Of Cases Per Country Per Province By Case Type From The First Recorded Case",
    "Description": "Returns all cases by case type for a country from the first recorded case. Country must be the country_slug from /countries. Cases must be one of: confirmed, recovered, deaths",
    "Path": "/dayone/country/{country}/status/{status}",
    "Params": [
      "country",
      "status"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Get List Of Cases Per Country By Case Type From The First Recorded Case",
    "Description": "Returns all cases by case type for a country from the first recorded case. Country must be the country_slug from /countries. Cases must be one of: confirmed, recovered, deaths",
    "Path": "/total/dayone/country/{country}/status/{status}",
    "Params": [
      "country",
      "status"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Get List Of Cases Per Country Per Province By Case Type From The First Recorded Case With Live Count",
    "Description": "Returns all cases by case type for a country from the first recorded case with the latest record being the live count. Country must be the country_slug from /countries. Cases must be one of: confirmed, recovered, deaths",
    "Path": "/dayone/country/{country}/status/{status}/live",
    "Params": [
      "country",
      "status"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Get Live List Of Cases Per Country Per Province By Case Type",
    "Description": "Returns all live cases by case type for a country. These records are pulled every 10 minutes and are ungrouped. Country must be the country_slug from /countries. Cases must be one of: confirmed, recovered, deaths",
    "Path": "/live/country/{country}/status/{status}",
    "Params": [
      "country",
      "status"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Get Live List Of Cases Per Country Per Province By Case Type After A Date",
    "Description": "Returns all live cases by case type for a country after a given date. These records are pulled every 10 minutes and are ungrouped. Country must be the country_slug from /countries. Cases must be one of: confirmed, recovered, deaths",
    "Path": "/live/country/{country}/status/{status}/date/{date}",
    "Params": [
      "country",
      "status",
      "date"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Add a webhook to be notified when new data becomes available",
    "Description": "POST Request must be in JSON format with key URL and the value of the webhook. Response data is the same as returned from /summary",
    "Path": "/webhook",
    "Params": [
      "URL",
      "webhook"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "Summary of new and total cases per country",
    "Description": "A summary of new and total cases per country",
    "Path": "/summary",
    "Params": null
  }
]
```

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackblitz.com/edit/read-local-json-file-service-78bnht in retrieving json value and display it in template..

Comment: What is stopping you? `{{text|json}}`

Answer (score 2):

Save your json in a variable and save your variable in the .ts file.

```
json: any = [{
    "Name": "Get All Data",
  }]
```

On html file:

```
<div *ngFor="let jsn of json">
{{ jsn.Name }}
```

Comment: I think its better to have the data in a JSON file and then retrieve the data from json. This will be useful if the data is large. Thus making the component looks simple. This is just an opinion. This code will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this in a JSON file and have this in a public property say `data`. Then using interpolation you can render this HTML.

```
{{data[0].Name}}
```

To get the data from json file you can use http:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Accept: "application/json"
  })
};

this.http.get("/assets/data.json", httpOptions).subscribe(
  (response: Olyimpics[]) => {
    this.rowData = response;
    this.gridApi.setPinnedBottomRowData(this.pinnedBottomRowData);
  },
  error => {
    console.log("Http error: ", error);
  }
);
```

You have inject the HttpClient in constructor:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
```

Also to display entire data, You need to use `*ngFor` directive.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the json pipe as simple as `{{data | json}}`